# Identify Wireless Adapter name and pipe into command

Tags: batch-file, command-line, pipe

I'm trying to use a batch script to identify the name of the wireless adapter (people rename them). then use the answer to restart that adapter. Is there a way to disconnect/reconnect with a specific profile that would be easier?

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=* skip=1" %%a in ('wmic.exe nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2 and netconnectionid like '%wi%'" get NetConnectionID') do output=%%A

netsh interface set interface name=%%A admin=disabled
netsh interface set interface name=%%A admin=enabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check next script (where *operational* commands are `ECHO`ed for debugging purposes only)

```
@echo OFF
for /f "tokens=2* delims==" %%a in (
  'wmic.exe nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2" get NetConnectionID /value'
) do (
    ECHO netsh interface set interface name="%%a" admin=disabled
    ECHO netsh interface set interface name="%%a" admin=enabled
)
```

Note:

- `%%a` variable name is case sensitive;
- `and netconnectionid like '%wi%'` omitted in `wmic` filter as you stated …*(people rename them)* yourself.